# PyCharm does not accept my Python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, web, pycharm

I'm working with Python framework Django.
I used Pycharm's terminal created virtual environment. {.\venv\Scripts\activate}
It was created, and i run the server with this python manage.py runserver
But the system responds:
No Python at "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
But i installed and using Python 3.11.2
And i have file manage.py in project1 folder
What should i do?

The code

```
PS D:\binkw32.dll\djangomorning> .\venv1\Scripts\activate
(venv1) PS D:\binkw32.dll\djangomorning> cd project1
(venv1) PS D:\binkw32.dll\djangomorning\project1> python manage.py runserver
No Python at 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe'
(venv1) PS D:\binkw32.dll\djangomorning\project1>
```

Comment: With what python version you created env ? Can you share the command you used for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key error is that you have installed venv of version **3.8.x**, and it tries to find the it, while you have base interpreter of version **3.11.x**.

In PyCharm go to `Settings` -> `Project` -> `Python Interpreter` -> `Add Interpreter`.

Hope it will solve your problem.